# How to get current time except from local machine

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php-carbon

I am making a daily report form using Larave 5.5 with XAMPP Local Apache server and MySQL database for an office project. This form will have to be filled daily and can't be changed after that day. So I have done the following to achieve this.

My code:

```
    $current_time =Carbon::now();
    dd($current_time);
    $current_date = $current_time->toDateString();
    $create_time = $dr_details->created_at->toDateString();
    if($current_date > $create_time){
        return redirect()->back()->with('message','Sorry! Time\'s up. Can\'t edit this DR anymore.');
    }
```

Now everything works fine until I try to find flaws in this. What I did is I changed the time of my machine to a previous date aaaaand the DR was editable again.
When I am changing the machine time, `Carbon::now()` gets that time.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Hi @Rian Zaman Please check this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-get-server-local-time-laravel-53

Comment: Thanks for the link. Tho I have searched and tried this already. This does not work for what I want. It does the same thing.

Comment: Hi @Rian Zaman first of check your config/app.php in 'timezone' set timezone your country like this 'timezone' => 'Asia/Dubai' and after check.

Comment: Done those already. Both in config/app.php and php.ini

Comment: Hi @Rian Zaman please edit question and add a config/app.php and your local machine time.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far i know you need to use javascript for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentTime = new Date();
var hours = currentTime.getHours();
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();


document.write(hours + ":" + minutes);
</script>
```

You must add-edit that for what your services want.

Comment: This won't work. It's the same as what I have done. It takes date / time from the machine.

Answer (score 0):

As apache server is local than it's means that it get time from your local machine and it's normal situation. When you deployes the project to production server it will be getting time from production server. You just will set time for your server once and it's all you need.

Comment: Hm, Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: @parthu_panther yes, and this is not the problem because time in production server set only one time you won't change it everytime.

Comment: @parthu_panther So, what you offer, any idea?

Comment: I have used the Carbon API which takes the machine time. Someone suggested me to define time zone name in `now()` function, like `Carbon::now('ASIA/DHAKA')`, this doesn't work either...

Comment: @parthu_panther I see no difference. If time can be changed in local or production then it can be changed on API server too and it won't helps him.